# 7-zip command-line to recursively extract archives in sub-directories, and output them into those sub-directories

Tags: windows, zip, 7-zip

I've got hundreds sub-directories, with each sub-directory having 1 or more archives in them. I want to recursively extract every archive in every sub-directory, with the extracted files ouputted in each sub-directory.

Starting with this:

```
DIR1
    SUBDIR2
    --->ZipFileA
    --->ZipFileB
    SUBDIR3
    --->ZipFileC
    --->ZipFileD
```

Want to end up with this:

```
DIR1
    SUBDIR2
    --->ExtractedZipFileA
    --->ExtractedZipFileB
    SUBDIR3
    --->ExtractedZipFileC
    --->ExtractedZipFileD
```

How do I do this?

I've tried...

```
7z x E:\Downloads\New -r -o*
```

... but this outputs everything in the main directory, rather than outputting them in their own sub-directories.

Comment: Could you use PowerShell instead?  E.g. `dir -Recurse -file -filter *.zip | %{Expand-Archive $_.FullName $_.PSParentPath}`

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked, although since my archives were CBZ rather than ZIP and since PowerShell doesn't extract ZIP archives with the CBZ extension, I needed to do `for /R %x in (*.CBZ) do ren "%x" *.ZIP` first

Answer (score 0):

Working like a charm:

```
for /r %a in (*.zip) do 7z.exe e "%~a" -o"%~dpa"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: what the hell are the arguments for 7z.exe?  please expand your answer.  the expansion of the commandline is not in the documentation